# How can I get username of a gtalk user using XMPP with google appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp, google-talk

I am using google appengine for my gtalk agent ,  I want to get the username of the gtalk user  how can I get it ?

for your reference, check this

```
XMPPService xmpp = XMPPServiceFactory.getXMPPService();
    //STEP 2
    Message msg = xmpp.parseMessage(req);
    JID fromJid = msg.getFromJid();
```

I am using the above things in the beginning .....

Answer (score 1):

The JID is [composed of](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview.html#JIDs_and_Resources) `user@domain/resource`.  The resource is optional, and provides more information about how the user is communicating (e.g. desktop or client app).

EDIT: See the Java [JID class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/xmpp/JID.html)

Comment: from that how can I extract Username ??? eg. if a user example@gmail.com chats , that user name should be extracted from the message received by servelet.. I want to put that in a string :) How can I do it ?

Comment: Hey Matthew , I got it. I can get the user ID like this

  String userid = fromJid.getId();

Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: You'll probably also want to strip out the resource.